# heroku staging - not able to push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am not able to push to staging for heroku.

When I am doing `git remote staging master`  I am getting

> fatal: 'staging' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Although I used to push to staging using the same command.

```
git remote -v
```

returns

> origin git@bitbucket.abc/test.git (fetch)
>   origin git@bitbucket.org:abc/test.git (push)

I tried to add a `git remote`, but It created something else and when I did `git push staging master`, It created another url of the app instead of pushing for the earlier staging url.

I am not able to resolve this. Also I am the owner of the heroku app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one git repo configured here, and that is a bitbucket git repo. You need to add the heroku configuration too. See [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) for reference.

Ultimately, run something like `heroku git:remote -a heroku-app-name -r staging`. Then you can do `git push staging master` and it'll push to the given app.